# Order of function applications

Tags: haskell

```
doubleMe :: Int -> Int
doubleMe x = x + x

doubleUs :: Int -> Int
doubleUs x y = doubleMe x+y
```

I'm trying to makes use of the function `doubleMe` to get double of sum of `x` and `y`. What am I doing wrong?

new code that doesn't compile:

```
doubleMe :: Int -> Int
doubleMe x = x + x

doubleUs :: Int -> Int -> Int
doubleUs x y = x*2 + y*2

doubleUs2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
doubleUs2 :: x y = doubleMe (x+y)
```

Comment: Look at `doubleUs2` again carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Function application has higher precedence than `+` and other operators, so `doubleMe x+y` is parsed as `(doubleMe x)+y`.  To fix this, write `doubleMe (x+y)`.

Answer (score 5):

Due to function application precedence you should use parentheses, also your `doubleUs` declaration is wrong as it takes two `Int`s:

```
doubleUs :: Int -> Int -> Int
doubleUs x y = doubleMe (x+y)
```

Comment: fair enough but when I try to compile this code, i get this:
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( double.hs, interpreted )

double.hs:8:14:
    Illegal type signature: ‘x y’
      Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables
    In a pattern type-signature

double.hs:8:30: Not in scope: ‘x’

double.hs:8:32: Not in scope: ‘y’
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: Can you edit your original post and append to it, your new code that is causing the new compiling error?

Comment: @user3050565 it works for me, probably there's a typographical error in your `double.hs`

Comment: @user3050565 `doubleUs2 :: x y = doubleMe (x+y)` should read ` `doubleUs2 x y = doubleMe (x+y)` (notice the lack of `::`).